# Pinescript initialisation

Tags: pine-script

I am trying to understand the following pinescript indicator code - https://www.tradingview.com/script/XzcIRUHv-JMA-RSX-Clone-LazyBear/

I am not sure what values variables like f90, f88 hold. Are they predefined short-cuts for something else? They seem to be arrays because they are used with index. E.g.:

```
f90_ = (nz(f90_[1]) == 0.0) ? 1.0 : (nz(f88[1]) <= nz(f90_[1])) ? nz(f88[1])+1 : nz(f90_[1])+1
```

Comment: Don't even try to understand that code. It is poorly written. They are just regular variables. `[]` in pinescript is used for accessing previous values of a series. So, for example; `close[2]` returns the close price of two bars back.

Comment: @BarisYakut in this case, I don't see what 'f90' is assigned to, is this aliased to some price element? very mysterious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not built-in variables.

`pine-script` versions 1 and 2 allow you to access variables with `[]` **in combination with** `nz()` even though the variable is not yet declared. So, the following is valid in *version 1* and *version 2*:

```
f90_ = (nz(f90_[1]) == 0.0) ? 1.0 : (nz(f88[1]) <= nz(f90_[1])) ? nz(f88[1])+1 : nz(f90_[1])+1
```

If you try this in `//@version=3`, you will get an **Undeclared identifier** error.

Let's shorten the code to the following:

```
//@version=2
study(title="JMA RSX Clone [LazyBear]", shorttitle="RSXC_LB", overlay=false)
length=input(14)

f90_ = (nz(f90_[1]) == 0.0) ? 1.0 : (nz(f88[1]) <= nz(f90_[1])) ? nz(f88[1])+1 : nz(f90_[1])+1
f88 = (nz(f90_[1]) == 0.0) and (length-1 >= 5) ? length-1.0 : 5.0 
plot(f90_, title="f90", color=orange, linewidth=4)
plot(f88, title="f88", color=red, linewidth=4)
```

Let's look at what happens to `f90_` and `f88` for the **very first bar**.

```
f90_ = (nz(f90_[1]) == 0.0) ? 1.0 : (nz(f88[1]) <= nz(f90_[1])) ? nz(f88[1])+1 : nz(f90_[1])+1
```

The condition here is `(nz(f90_[1]) == 0.0)`. `f90_[1]` is basically asking the value of one previous bar, but this is the first bar (remember?), so there is no previous value. So, the answer is **NaN** (Not A Number).

Now, if you put this in `nz()`, it will return **zero**. Because `nz()` replaces *NaN* values with *zeros*.

So the condition will be true for the first bar, and `f90_` will be assigned to ***1.0***.

Let's look at `f88` now, again for the **very first bar**.

```
f88 = (nz(f90_[1]) == 0.0) and (length-1 >= 5) ? length-1.0 : 5.0
```

The first condition here is `(nz(f90_[1]) == 0.0)`. This should return `true`, because of the same reason above.

The second condition is `(length-1 >= 5)`. This should also return true for the default input (14).

So, `f88` will be assigned to 14-1 = ***13*** for the first bar.

I think you can continue from here on. Try to run the short code I provided and see the chart.